# Why Bitbake recipe is looking for lib in wrong folder?

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I have x2 cmake bitbake recipes trying to build for Orocos RTT & OCL under yocto dunfell. OCL depends on RTT. RTT compiles ok, but OCL errors it can't find **libcap-ng.so**. I have added the libcap-ng dependency in both recipes. From the error it looks like it is because it is looking for the lib in the RTT folder instead of the OCL folder. At this stage RTT has finished compiling successfully and the RTT work directory is empty, so its not there.

> 'ERROR: orocos-ocl-git-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/user/rpi/build/tmp/work/arm1176jzfshf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/orocos-ocl/git-r0/temp/run.do_compile.10683' failed with exit code 1:
> ninja: error: '/home/user/rpi/build/tmp/work/arm1176jzfshf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/orocos-rtt/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcap-ng.so', needed by 'ocl/orocos/gnulinux/ocl/types/libocl-gnulinux.so.2.10.0', missing and no known rule to make it'

OCL Recipe:

```
    SUMMARY = "Orocos ocl"
    LICENSE = "GPLv2"
    LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/GPL-2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    
    SRCREV = "e454c4d592c3ed8aa9f887495e78ee9a755cccde"
    SRC_URI = "git://github.com/orocos-toolchain/ocl.git;protocol=git;branch=toolchain-2.10"
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    
    DEPENDS = "orocos-rtt libedit boost libcap-ng "

    S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

    EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON -DBUILD_LUA_RTT=OFF -DBUILD_REPORTING_NETCDF=OFF -DBUILD_LOGGING=OFF -DNETCDF_INSTALL=OFF -DBUILD_DEPLOYMENT=ON -DBUILD_HELLOWORLD=OFF -DDEFAULT_PLUGIN_PATH=${libdir} -DNO_GPL=ON -DBUILD_RTALLOC=ON"

    inherit cmake pkgconfig

    do_install_append () {
            ..... blah
    }
```

Why is it looking in the wrong folder? What's the best way to address this? How can I force it look locally?

Comment: This does not look like a Yocto issue to me (recipes don't know about each others work directories). Show your CMakeLists: it sounds like there might be a hard coded directory somewhere

Comment: `-DDEFAULT_PLUGIN_PATH=${STAGING_LIBDIR}` instead of `-DDEFAULT_PLUGIN_PATH=${libdir}`? At least it seems fishy to start with.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I changed STAGING_LIBDIR. Base cmake lists are in the github repos. 
[RTT Repo](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/ocl/tree/toolchain-2.10)
[OCL Repo](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/rtt/blob/toolchain-2.10)

Both have there own /config/check_depend.cmake. It doesn't make sense to me that its complaining about libcap-ng lib in OCL, because from these check_depends it looks that only RTT check_depend looks for libcap-ng. And RTT is building fine?